# Differing results in background worker-VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, backgroundworker

I have a strange issue while using Background Worker in VB.NET:
I have the following code in a form:

```
 Private Sub CalculateAccounts()
    con.Open()
    Dim SQLDelTrial As String = "DELETE TrialBalance.* FROM TrialBalance;"
    Command = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLDelTrial, con)
    Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

    con.Close()

    Dim CountAccounts As String = "Select * From AccountLedger"
    Dim DACountAccounts As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSCountAccounts As New DataSet

    DACountAccounts = New OleDbDataAdapter(CountAccounts, con)
    DACountAccounts.Fill(DSCountAccounts, "DSCountAccountHere")

    Dim Count As Long
    For Count = 0 To DSCountAccounts.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        AccountCode = DSCountAccounts.Tables(0).Rows(Count).Item(0)
        Dim AccountNormal As Integer
        AccountNormal = DSCountAccounts.Tables(0).Rows(Count).Item(11)

        If AccountNormal = 1 Then        'Debit Account
            Call CalculateDebitAccount()
        ElseIf AccountNormal = 2 Then    'Credit Account
            Call CalculateCreditAccount()
        End If
    Next
    Call UpdateDGV()

End Sub
Private Sub CalculateDebitAccount()

    Dim TranConsDebitTotal As Decimal
    Dim SQLDebitTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.DebitedAmount) AS SumOfDebitedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated)GROUP BY TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

    Dim DADebitTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSDebitTotal As New DataSet

    DADebitTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLDebitTotal, con)
    DADebitTotal.Fill(DSDebitTotal, "DSDebitTotalHere")

    If DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        TranConsDebitTotal = DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    End If


    Dim TranConsCreditTotal As Decimal
    Dim SQLCreditTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.CreditedAmount) AS SumOfCreditedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated) GROUP BY TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

    Dim DACreditTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSCreditTotal As New DataSet

    DACreditTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLCreditTotal, con)
    DACreditTotal.Fill(DSCreditTotal, "DSCreditTotalHere")

    If DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        TranConsCreditTotal = DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    End If
    Dim SQLAccountOpening As String = "SELECT AccountLedger.ID, AccountLedger.AccOpBal FROM(AccountLedger) WHERE (((AccountLedger.ID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

    Dim DAAccountOpening As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSAccountOpening As New DataSet

    DAAccountOpening = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLAccountOpening, con)
    DAAccountOpening.Fill(DSAccountOpening, "DSAccountOpeningHere")

    Dim AccountNetBal As Decimal
    If IsDBNull(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) Then
        AccountNetBal = TranConsDebitTotal - TranConsCreditTotal
    Else

        AccountNetBal = (Val(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) + TranConsDebitTotal) - TranConsCreditTotal
    End If
    ' MsgBox(AccountNetBal)

    Dim SQLTrialBalance As String = "Select * From TrialBalance"
    Dim DATrialBalance As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSTrialBalance As New DataSet

    Dim TrialNewRow As DataRow

    DATrialBalance = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLTrialBalance, con)
    DATrialBalance.Fill(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")


    If chkZeroBal.Checked = True Then
        TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
        If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
            TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
            TrialNewRow.Item(2) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
            TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
        Else
            TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
            TrialNewRow.Item(1) = AccountNetBal
            TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
        End If
        DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
    Else

        If AccountNetBal <> 0 Then
            TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
            If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
                TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                TrialNewRow.Item(2) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
                TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
            Else
                TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                TrialNewRow.Item(1) = AccountNetBal
                TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
            End If
            DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
        End If

    End If
        Dim CBTrialBalance As New OleDbCommandBuilder(DATrialBalance)
        DATrialBalance.Update(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")
End Sub

Private Sub CalculateCreditAccount()
    Dim TranConsDebitTotal As Decimal
    Dim SQLDebitTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.DebitedAmount) AS SumOfDebitedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated)GROUP BY TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

    Dim DADebitTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSDebitTotal As New DataSet

    DADebitTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLDebitTotal, con)
    DADebitTotal.Fill(DSDebitTotal, "DSDebitTotalHere")

    If DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        TranConsDebitTotal = DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    End If


    Dim TranConsCreditTotal As Decimal
    Dim SQLCreditTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.CreditedAmount) AS SumOfCreditedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated) GROUP BY TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

    Dim DACreditTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSCreditTotal As New DataSet

    DACreditTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLCreditTotal, con)
    DACreditTotal.Fill(DSCreditTotal, "DSCreditTotalHere")

    If DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
        TranConsCreditTotal = DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
    End If
    Dim SQLAccountOpening As String = "SELECT AccountLedger.ID, AccountLedger.AccOpBal FROM(AccountLedger) WHERE (((AccountLedger.ID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

    Dim DAAccountOpening As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSAccountOpening As New DataSet

    DAAccountOpening = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLAccountOpening, con)
    DAAccountOpening.Fill(DSAccountOpening, "DSAccountOpeningHere")

    Dim AccountNetBal As Decimal
    If IsDBNull(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) Then
        AccountNetBal = TranConsCreditTotal - TranConsDebitTotal
    Else

        AccountNetBal = (Val(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) + TranConsCreditTotal) - TranConsDebitTotal
    End If
    ' MsgBox(AccountNetBal)

    Dim SQLTrialBalance As String = "Select * From TrialBalance"
    Dim DATrialBalance As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSTrialBalance As New DataSet

    Dim TrialNewRow As DataRow

    DATrialBalance = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLTrialBalance, con)
    DATrialBalance.Fill(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")




    If chkZeroBal.Checked = True Then
        TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
        If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
            TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
            TrialNewRow.Item(1) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
            TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
        Else
            TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
            TrialNewRow.Item(2) = AccountNetBal
            TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
        End If
        DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
    Else

        If AccountNetBal <> 0 Then
            TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
            If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
                TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                TrialNewRow.Item(1) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
                TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
            Else
                TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                TrialNewRow.Item(2) = AccountNetBal
                TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
            End If
            DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
        End If

    End If
    Dim CBTrialBalance As New OleDbCommandBuilder(DATrialBalance)
    DATrialBalance.Update(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")
End Sub



 Private Sub BackgroundWorker1_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs) Handles BackgroundWorker1.DoWork

    Dim CountAccounts As String = "Select * From AccountLedger"
    Dim DACountAccounts As New OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim DSCountAccounts As New DataSet

    DACountAccounts = New OleDbDataAdapter(CountAccounts, Con)
    DACountAccounts.Fill(DSCountAccounts, "DSCountAccountHere")

    Dim Count As Long
    For Count = 0 To DSCountAccounts.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

        AccountCode = DSCountAccounts.Tables(0).Rows(Count).Item(0)
        Dim AccountNormal As Integer = DSCountAccounts.Tables(0).Rows(Count).Item(11)

        If AccountNormal = 1 Then        'Debit Account
            ' Call CalculateDebitAccount()
            Dim TranConsDebitTotal As Decimal
            Dim SQLDebitTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.DebitedAmount) AS SumOfDebitedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated)GROUP BY TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

            Dim DADebitTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSDebitTotal As New DataSet

            DADebitTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLDebitTotal, Con)
            DADebitTotal.Fill(DSDebitTotal, "DSDebitTotalHere")

            If DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                TranConsDebitTotal = DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
            End If

            Dim TranConsCreditTotal As Decimal
            Dim SQLCreditTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.CreditedAmount) AS SumOfCreditedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated) GROUP BY TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

            Dim DACreditTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSCreditTotal As New DataSet

            DACreditTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLCreditTotal, Con)
            DACreditTotal.Fill(DSCreditTotal, "DSCreditTotalHere")

            If DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                TranConsCreditTotal = DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
            End If
            Dim SQLAccountOpening As String = "SELECT AccountLedger.ID, AccountLedger.AccOpBal FROM(AccountLedger) WHERE (((AccountLedger.ID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

            Dim DAAccountOpening As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSAccountOpening As New DataSet

            DAAccountOpening = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLAccountOpening, Con)
            DAAccountOpening.Fill(DSAccountOpening, "DSAccountOpeningHere")

            Dim AccountNetBal As Decimal
            If IsDBNull(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) Then
                AccountNetBal = TranConsDebitTotal - TranConsCreditTotal
            Else

                AccountNetBal = (Val(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) + TranConsDebitTotal) - TranConsCreditTotal
            End If
            ' MsgBox(AccountNetBal)

            Dim SQLTrialBalance As String = "Select * From TrialBalance"
            Dim DATrialBalance As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSTrialBalance As New DataSet

            Dim TrialNewRow As DataRow

            DATrialBalance = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLTrialBalance, Con)
            DATrialBalance.Fill(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")


            If chkZeroBal.Checked = True Then
                TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
                If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
                    TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                    TrialNewRow.Item(2) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
                    TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
                Else
                    TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                    TrialNewRow.Item(1) = AccountNetBal
                    TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
                End If
                DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
            Else

                If AccountNetBal <> 0 Then
                    TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
                    If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
                        TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                        TrialNewRow.Item(2) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
                        TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
                    Else
                        TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                        TrialNewRow.Item(1) = AccountNetBal
                        TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
                    End If
                    DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
                End If

            End If
            Dim CBTrialBalance As New OleDbCommandBuilder(DATrialBalance)
            DATrialBalance.Update(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")

        ElseIf AccountNormal = 2 Then    'Credit Account
            'Call CalculateCreditAccount()
            Dim TranConsDebitTotal As Decimal
            Dim SQLDebitTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.DebitedAmount) AS SumOfDebitedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated)GROUP BY TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.DebitedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

            Dim DADebitTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSDebitTotal As New DataSet

            DADebitTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLDebitTotal, Con)
            DADebitTotal.Fill(DSDebitTotal, "DSDebitTotalHere")

            If DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                TranConsDebitTotal = DSDebitTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
            End If


            Dim TranConsCreditTotal As Decimal
            Dim SQLCreditTotal As String = "SELECT TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID, Sum(TranConsolidated.CreditedAmount) AS SumOfCreditedAmount FROM(TranConsolidated) GROUP BY TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID HAVING (((TranConsolidated.CreditedAccID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

            Dim DACreditTotal As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSCreditTotal As New DataSet

            DACreditTotal = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLCreditTotal, Con)
            DACreditTotal.Fill(DSCreditTotal, "DSCreditTotalHere")

            If DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows.Count <> 0 Then
                TranConsCreditTotal = DSCreditTotal.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)
            End If
            Dim SQLAccountOpening As String = "SELECT AccountLedger.ID, AccountLedger.AccOpBal FROM(AccountLedger) WHERE (((AccountLedger.ID)=" & AccountCode & "));"

            Dim DAAccountOpening As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSAccountOpening As New DataSet

            DAAccountOpening = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLAccountOpening, Con)
            DAAccountOpening.Fill(DSAccountOpening, "DSAccountOpeningHere")

            Dim AccountNetBal As Decimal
            If IsDBNull(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) Then
                AccountNetBal = TranConsCreditTotal - TranConsDebitTotal
            Else

                AccountNetBal = (Val(DSAccountOpening.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1)) + TranConsCreditTotal) - TranConsDebitTotal
            End If
            ' MsgBox(AccountNetBal)

            Dim SQLTrialBalance As String = "Select * From TrialBalance"
            Dim DATrialBalance As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim DSTrialBalance As New DataSet

            Dim TrialNewRow As DataRow

            DATrialBalance = New OleDbDataAdapter(SQLTrialBalance, Con)
            DATrialBalance.Fill(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")




            If chkZeroBal.Checked = True Then
                TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
                If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
                    TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                    TrialNewRow.Item(1) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
                    TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
                Else
                    TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                    TrialNewRow.Item(2) = AccountNetBal
                    TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
                End If
                DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
            Else

                If AccountNetBal <> 0 Then
                    TrialNewRow = DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).NewRow()
                    If AccountNetBal < 0 Then
                        TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                        TrialNewRow.Item(1) = Math.Abs(AccountNetBal)
                        TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 0
                    Else
                        TrialNewRow.Item(0) = AccountCode
                        TrialNewRow.Item(2) = AccountNetBal
                        TrialNewRow.Item(3) = 1
                    End If
                    DSTrialBalance.Tables(0).Rows.Add(TrialNewRow)
                End If

            End If
            Dim CBTrialBalance As New OleDbCommandBuilder(DATrialBalance)
            DATrialBalance.Update(DSTrialBalance, "DSTrialBalanceHere")
        End If
    Next
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    BackgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(AccountCode)
    ' Call UpdateDGV()
End Sub
```

When I run the first three Subs in the form itself,the results of the calculation are accurate.However,running the near similar code in the backgroundworker returns completely wrong results.
What am doing wrong while coding in the backgroundworker?

Khalid.

Comment: That's just too much code to read through for a very vague question. It would be helpful if you could show how the results differ to help narrow down the problem location.

Comment: What you are doing wrong is not debugging.  You don't fix issues like this simply by reading the code.  You fix them by running the code and watching it in action.  Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and then step through it line by line, testing the values of all relevant variables and expressions at each step.  As soon as reality doesn't match expectation, you've found an issue.  At the very least, you can provide us with that relevant information, but you may well be able to fix the issue yourself.

Comment: "near similar code" is not the same code. So work out what the difference is, potentially there's something happening as a result of the way you've changed it. Background workers are asynchronous so at a guess there might be an issue with data not being present at the time it runs, for instance. As the comment above says you need to step through the code and examine it. You haven't given enough specific detail of the issue ("results are wrong" does not constitute a description of the issue that we can work with) or narrowed down things to the particular bit of code that breaks.